# Template of syncfusion chart tooltip not getting x and y values of point

Tags: syncfusion

I am using a SyncFusion library to develop Smith Chart. I have to change the tooltip of the chart. I am using template property of tooltip but it not working. Code:

```
tooltip={{ visible: true,  template: '${X}' }}
```

In the tooltip it i get `undefined`. How can i get the value of `x` and `y` in `template` of tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

We are glad to announce that our v18.1.44 patch release is rolled out, we have added the fix for the reported issue and is available for download under the following link.

NPM Packages: https://www.npmjs.com/~syncfusionorg

We appreciate your patience in waiting for this release. Let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: Can you give an example of how to use it or provide some documentation ? I could not found any documentation for it . @Srihari